# How to read a registry value using TRegistry in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, registry, delphi-12-athens

I'm trying to read registry values in Windows using the `TRegistry` class.

Someone sent me an example of how it can be used, but the code isn't working.

```
uses Windows, Registry;

...

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Registry: TRegistry;
  ProductName: string;
begin
  Registry := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ); // or KEY_WRITE if you want to modify the value
  try
    Registry.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    ProductName := Registry.GetValue('SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion', 'ProductName', '');
    ShowMessage('The product name is: ' + ProductName);
  finally
    Registry.Free;
  end;
end;
```

It's not finding `GetValue`. So perhaps this is not how `TRegistry` works or perhaps the way it works has changed in newer versions of Delphi. I am not sure and the Embarcadero docwiki is down, so I can't check there either.

How does `TRegistry` work? How can I use it to read values from the registry?

Comment: Did you try to put the caret after "Registry." and pressing Ctrl+Space? Then surely you saw ReadString, ReadInteger, ReadBoolean etc?

Comment: And did you try to Google "Delphi Registry"? There are thousands of examples on the WWW.

Comment: Did you try to put the caret inside TRegistry and pressing F1?

Comment: That "_someone_" must have confused Delphi [with .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue?view=net-8.0) or just made up facts using AI. The Registry enforces data types, distinguishing also texts from numbers. You can easily verify that by using `regedit.exe` at least once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no GetValue method on TRegistry, so the code they have sent you is wrong, or they use a helper class that they have not provided. One way would be to do this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Registry: TRegistry;
  ProductName: string;
begin
  Registry := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ); // or KEY_WRITE if you want to modify the value
  try
    Registry.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    ProductName := '';
    if Registry.OpenKey('SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion', False) then
    try
      ProductName := Registry.ReadString('ProductName');
    finally
      Registry.CloseKey;
    end;
    ShowMessage('The product name is: ' + ProductName);
  finally
    Registry.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: When just reading a key, you should prefer `OpenKeyReadOnly()` instead of `KEY_READ+OpenKey()`, especially when `HKLM` is used, eg: `Registry := TRegistry.Create; ... if Registry.OpenKeyReadOnly('SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion') then ... `

Answer (score 0):

The Embarcadero Doku on TRegistry is available:

[Using TRegistry](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Using_TRegistry)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Here you have an example:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   reg: TRegistry;
begin
   reg:= TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ);
   reg.RootKey:=  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
   reg.OpenKey('SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion', false);
   ShowMessage(reg.ReadString('ProductName'));
   reg.Free;
end;
```

Comment: That's a poor example because you don't protect your registry object and you don't check your return values. Also, this code-only answer doesn't add anything new to this Q.

Comment: "_Here you have an example_" is just prosa but no explanation at all - you could have linked at least to any documentation (Delphi or WinAPI).